# How to strsplit different number of strings in certain column by do function

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have a problem with split column value when element of column has different number of strings. I can do it in plyr e.g.:

```
library(plyr)
column <- c("jake", "jane jane","john john john")
df <- data.frame(1:3, name = column)
df$name <- as.character(df$name)
df2 <- ldply(strsplit(df$name, " "), rbind)
View(df2)
```

As a result, we have data frame with number of column related to maximum number of stings in given element.

When I try to do it in dplyr, I used `do` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  do(data.frame(strsplit(.$name, " ")))
```

but I get an error:

> ```
> Error in data.frame("jake", c("jane", "jane"), c("john", "john", "john" : 
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3
> ```

It seems to me that it should be used `rbind` function but I do not know where.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're having troubles because `strsplit()` returns a list which we then need to apply `as.data.frame.list()` to each element to get it into the proper format that `dplyr` requires. Even then it would still require a bit more work to get usable results.  Long story short, it doesn't seem like a suitable operation for `do()`.

I think you might be better off using  `separate()` from `tidyr`.  It can easily be used with `dplyr` functions and chains.  It's not clear whether you want to keep the first column since your `ldply` result for `df2` does not have it, so I left it off.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df[-1], name, 1:3, " ", extra = "merge")
#      1    2    3
# 1 jake <NA> <NA>
# 2 jane jane <NA>
# 3 john john john
```

You could also use `cSplit`.  It is also very efficient since it relies on `data.table`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df[-1], "name", " ")
#    name_1 name_2 name_3
# 1:   jake     NA     NA
# 2:   jane   jane     NA
# 3:   john   john   john
```

Or more specifically

```
setnames(df2 <- cSplit(df[-1], "name", " "), names(df2), as.character(1:3))
df2
#       1    2    3
# 1: jake   NA   NA
# 2: jane jane   NA
# 3: john john john
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. But what if we do not know how many strings are in given element of column?

Comment: If you don't know how many columns there will be, then I would use `cSplit` because it does that work for you.  Nice first question by the way.  Clearly asked and reproducible.  +1

Comment: @Nicolabo, You could first use `stringr::str_count` to determine the max. no of columns you'd need and then use `tidyr::separate`. Something like this - 

`len = max(str_count(string = df$name, pattern = " "));`
`vec_names = paste0("X", 1:(len + 1));`
`separate(df[-1], name, vec_names, " ", extra = "merge");`