# split dataframe with multiple delimiters in R

Tags: r, splitstackshape

```
df1 <- 
     Gene             GeneLocus 
    CPA1|1357       chr7:130020290-130027948:+     
    GUCY2D|3000     chr17:7905988-7923658:+   
    UBC|7316        chr12:125396194-125399577:-            
    C11orf95|65998  chr11:63527365-63536113:-        
    ANKMY2|57037    chr7:16639413-16685398:-
```

expected output

```
df2 <- 
     Gene.1   Gene.2             chr     start     end 
    CPA1      1357               7     130020290 130027948   
    GUCY2D    3000               17      7905988   7923658  
    UBC       7316               12    125396194 125399577          
    C11orf95  65998              11     63527365  63536113     
    ANKMY2    57037               7     16639413  16685398]]
```

I tried this way..

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
df1 <- cSplit(df1,"Gene", sep="|", direction="wide", fixed=T)
df1 <- cSplit(df1,"GeneLocus",sep=":",direction="wide", fixed=T)
df1 <- cSplit(df1,"GeneLocus_2",sep="-",direction="wide", fixed=T)
df1 <- data.frame(df1)
df2$GeneLocus_1 <- gsub("chr","", df1$GeneLocus_1)
```

I would like to know if there is any other alternative way to do it in simpler way

Comment: Looks quite straightforward to me. You could also have a look at `separate` from the `tidyr` package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237835/how-to-strsplit-different-number-of-strings-in-certain-column-by-do-function-dp.

Comment: You can use `DT <- cSplit(df1, 1:2, '[+|:-]', fixed=FALSE)[, c(1:2, 5:7), with=FALSE][, GeneLocus_1:=as.numeric(sub('[a-z]+', '', GeneLocus_1))]` and then change the column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...Just ignore the warning that does not affect the output; it actually has the side effect of removing the strand information (`:+` or `:-`).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% separate(Gene, c("Gene.1","Gene.2")) %>% separate(GeneLocus, c("chr","start","end")) %>% mutate(chr=sub("chr","",chr))
```

Output:

```
    Gene.1 Gene.2 chr     start       end
1     CPA1   1357   7 130020290 130027948
2   GUCY2D   3000  17   7905988   7923658
3      UBC   7316  12 125396194 125399577
4 C11orf95  65998  11  63527365  63536113
5   ANKMY2  57037   7  16639413  16685398
```

Comment: seems perfect answer for what OP wanted. But I will probably do `df1 %>% separate(Gene, c("Gene.1","Gene.2")) %>% separate(GeneLocus, c("chr","start","end","strand"), "[|:-]") %>% mutate(chr=sub("chr","",chr))%>%mutate(strand=ifelse(strand=="+","+","-"))` just to keep strand info. (as a genomics student)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like the following approach:

1. Make a single delimiter in your "GeneLocus" column (and strip out the unnecessary parts while you're at it).
2. Split both columns at once. Note that `cSplit` "balances" the columns being split according to the number of output columns detected. Thus, since the first column would only result in 2 columns when split, but the second would result in 4, you would need to drop columns 3 and 4 from the result.

```
library(splitstackshape)

GLPat <- "^chr(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([+-])$"
cSplit(as.data.table(mydf)[, GeneLocus := gsub(
  GLPat, "\\1|\\2|\\3|\\4", GeneLocus)], names(mydf), "|")[
    , 3:4 := NULL, with = FALSE][]
#      Gene_1 Gene_2 GeneLocus_1 GeneLocus_2 GeneLocus_3 GeneLocus_4
# 1:     CPA1   1357           7   130020290   130027948           +
# 2:   GUCY2D   3000          17     7905988     7923658           +
# 3:      UBC   7316          12   125396194   125399577           -
# 4: C11orf95  65998          11    63527365    63536113           -
# 5:   ANKMY2  57037           7    16639413    16685398           -
```

---

Alternatively, you can try `col_flatten` from my "SOfun" package, with which you can do:

```
library(SOfun)

Pat <- "^chr(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([+-])$"
Fun <- function(invec) strsplit(gsub(Pat, "\\1|\\2|\\3|\\4", invec), "|", TRUE)

col_flatten(as.data.table(mydf)[, lapply(.SD, Fun)], names(mydf), drop = TRUE)
#      Gene_1 Gene_2 GeneLocus_1 GeneLocus_2 GeneLocus_3 GeneLocus_4
# 1:     CPA1   1357           7   130020290   130027948           +
# 2:   GUCY2D   3000          17     7905988     7923658           +
# 3:      UBC   7316          12   125396194   125399577           -
# 4: C11orf95  65998          11    63527365    63536113           -
# 5:   ANKMY2  57037           7    16639413    16685398           -
```

SOfun is only on GitHub, so you can install it with:

```
source("http://news.mrdwab.com/install_github.R")
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")
```